# jQuery - autocomplete doesn't display results from database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I am working with jQuery autocomplete plugin and this is my index:

```
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tag").autocomplete({source: "./search.php?q="+ $("#tag").val()});
   });
</script>

<form action="search.php" method="post" class="form-inline search">
  <input type="text" id="tag" name="tag">
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search" />
</form>
```

in `search.php` which is in the same folder as `index.php` is following:

```
 include 'config.php';
 $q=$_GET['q'];
 $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);

 $sql="SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE '%$my_data%'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

 if($result)
 {
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo $row['tag']."\n";
  }
 }
```

When I start typing, autocomplete doesn't offer me any suggestions. Also no errors in JS console. In the code is just displayed `No search results.`.
The paths are set up correctly, the database connection as well.

Thus, where could be a problem?

Thank you

Comment: do you see any results when you access search.php?q=something directly?

Comment: Yes, I see the results there, on the blank page.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a query string on the src url of autocomplete.
Just write your src file without query string:

```
$("#tag").autocomplete({source: "./search.php"});
```

And in your php file you have to capture the term parameter:

```
$q = $_GET['term'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this way - in PHP file must be data returned in JSON:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
    $result[] = $row['tag'];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```